# how to merge same key in an array in php

Tags: php, arrays

i want to transform this array

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [text] => i
            [age] => 30
            [gender] => male
            [job] => driver
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [text] => am
            [age] => 30
            [gender] => male
            [job] => driver
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [text] => bob
            [age] => 30
            [gender] => male
            [job] => driver
        )

        

)
```

into this

```
Array
(
    [details] => Array
        (
            [text] => i am Bob
            [age] => 30
            [gender] => male
            [job] => driver
        )
)
```

i have tried array merge `array_merge($array1,$array2);` using foreach loop no luck..needless to post here the tried code any idea how to achieve this kind of operations

Comment: show your code with `using foreach loop no luck`

Comment: Also, what is the basis of merge?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just need to loop through and test to see if you've already populated the item - if not, add to is

```
$details = [];
foreach ($array as $info) {
  foreach ($info as $key => $val) {
    if (!isset($details[$key])) $details[$key] = $val;
    else {
      if ($details[$key] != $val) $details[$key].= " " . $val;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```js
$array = //your array
$array2 = array();
$add = "";
foreach($array as $value) {
  $add .= $array ['text'];
  $array2['details']['age'] = $value['age'];
  $array2['details']['gender'] = $value['gender'];
  $array2['details']['job'] = $value['job'];
}
$array2.unshift($add);
print_r($array2);
```